# Storing maximum transaction amount and retaining second highest transaction amount in a lookback period

Tags: python, sql, hive, hiveql

I have the following query (HiveQL) which calculates the maximum transaction amount for a customer from the date the transaction was made and retains the previous maximum transaction amount previous to the date the transaction was made.

#### Query

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE TXN_AMT AS
    SELECT *, 
          MAX(TXN_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST ORDER BY TXN_DATE DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS MAX
          MAX(TXN_AMT) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST ORDER BY TXN_DATE DESC ROWS BETWEEN 1 AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as Max2
   FROM dataset; 
QUIT;
```

#### Example of output data

```
cust txn_date txn_amt max max2   
1    29/3/20   100    100  70  
1    28/3/20   50     70   20  
1    2/3/20    20     70   20  
1    15/2/20   70     70   - (no previous txn to take max2)
```

#### Issue

I need to run this query on a dataset that has millions of rows. Unfortunately this query won't run for a 360k row dataset.

#### Solutions Tried

I have tried running the query directly on Hive & Spark with no success - the run time is too long. I have tried rewriting the code using the lag() function but to no great success.

Does anyone know how to rewrite the above query to produce the desired output with optimal performance? The query needs to be in Python or HiveQL.

Thanks

Comment: Hive really should have no trouble running this query on 360k rows -- unless perhaps you only have a handful of customers.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - Having real problems with execution time. I've tried connecting to Hive on different servers available but no joy. I'll speak to the team that manages Hive tomorrow. There's about 900 distinct customers in the 360k dataset.

Answer (score 0):

My guess for the performance issue is that you have some outlier customers with zilions of transactions.  My guess is that Hive is going the `order by` component of the window function on a single processor.

You can check if you have any outliers with an aggregation:

```
select cust, count(*)
from dataset
group by cust
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you then filter out the outlier from your query, you might find that it works much better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. It seemed like the full query was being performed on a single processor. Is there a way to change settings to sort this?

Comment: @SRobo . . . I don't know why Hive would run the entire query on a single processor.  It should be able to parallelize the `partition by`.